# Draw 2D image on to the Targetmarker

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, vuforia

I have a doubt regarding the drawing of 2d image on to the targetmarker. I am using vuforia sample examples for this and they were drawing teapot on to the marker. I want to draw 2d image, and rotate the image 180 but the problem is it is drawing as a cube and I am not able to see the image after 90degree since the image is at the top visible plane. Therefore when the plane passes the 90 degree bottom plane is visible. Can anyone please help me out in drawing 2d image(plane).

Comment: If its 2D, then it's obviously got only 2 dimension. Length and Height. If you flip it 90degrees, there will not be any depth to see.

Comment: @Augmented Jacob-Can you help me to make image visible after 90 degrees?

Comment: I use Vuforia Unity, so it's a little easier there. From the looks of your previous question, I think you're using Vuforia SDK.

Comment: @Augmented Jacob-You are right. I am using Vuforia SDK. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, actually that was a 2D image and not a cube. Now I am able to get the image visible after it is rotated beyond 90 degree. I just removed the GL_CULL_FACE and now I am able to see the image.